# Unused Vs. Unallocated Space

Tags: sql-server

The unallocated space is 376 487.94 MB .What is the best practices to get back 376 Go ?

[image]

Comment: Does Shrink solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to shrink the database?

You can do this either with right click on db's name, Tasks, shrink + dialog, or with the command

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(N'QlikDataWarehouse' )
```

This may be a very long lasting process! And make sure to take a backup first!

Also make sure, that there's enough disk space for the transaction log which will get quite big.

One more hint: Check if there's a max file size set (right click on database, options, files). I once had severe problems with this operation when the transaction log could not grow due to this max size...